# jquery change css when anywhere else is clicked besides div

Tags: jquery

Right now I'm having a bit of an issue, as I've just been learning javascript/jquery this last week.

My code is currently setup so that there is a menu and a search bar right next to eachother. When the menu is clicked, the search bar disappears. When the search bar is clicked the menu disappears. And when anywhere else on the document is clicked, they go back to their default state. Problem is when I click one of the submenu buttons, the thing goes back to default as well. So I'm trying to figure out a way to make the menu stay open when a drop down menu is clicked.

**[Here is my jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PnU34/)**

Here is the bit of jquery I'm using to accomplish the hiding/showing:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('.input-text').on('focus', function() {
    $('#mobnav-trigger').css({
        display: 'none'
    });
    $('#search_mini_form').css({
        width: '100%',
        transition: 'width .4s ease'
    });
    $('#search_mini_form .input-text').css({
        height: '45px',
        border: '2px solid #16a085'
    });
});
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( ! $(e.target).closest('.input-text').length ) {
        $('#mobnav-trigger').css({
            display: 'block'
        });
        $('#search_mini_form').css({
        width: '48%',
        transition: 'width 0s'
        });
        $('#search_mini_form .input-text').css({
        height: '49px',
        border: '0'
    });
    }
});
$('#mobnav-trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('#search_mini_form').css({
        display: 'none'
    });
    $('#mobnav').css({
        width: '100%',
        transition: 'width .4s ease'
    });
    $('.vertnav-top.mobile').css({
        width: '100%',
        maxHeight: '9999px',
        transition: 'width .0s'
    });
    $('.vertnav-top.mobile.show').css({
        maxHeight: '9999px'
    });
});
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( ! $(e.target).closest('#mobnav-trigger').length ) {
        $('#search_mini_form').css({
            display: 'block'
        });
        $('#mobnav').css({
        width: '48%',
        transition: 'width 0s'
        });
        $('.vertnav-top.mobile').css({
        width: '48%',
        transition: 'width 0s',
        maxHeight: '0px'
        });
        $('.vertnav-top.mobile.show').css({
        maxHeight: '0px'
        });
    }
});
$('.opener').on('click', function() {
    $('#search_mini_form').css({
        display: 'none'
    });
    $('#mobnav').css({
        width: '100%',
        transition: 'width .4s ease'
    });
    $('.vertnav-top.mobile').css({
        width: '100%',
        maxHeight: '9999px',
        transition: 'width .0s'
    });
    $('.vertnav-top.mobile.show').css({
        maxHeight: '9999px'
    });
});
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( ! $(e.target).closest('.nav-container').length ) {
        $('#search_mini_form').css({
            display: 'block'
        });
        $('#mobnav').css({
        width: '48%',
        transition: 'width 0s'
        });
        $('.vertnav-top.mobile').css({
        width: '48%',
        transition: 'width 0s',
        maxHeight: '0px'
        });
        $('.vertnav-top.mobile.show').css({
        maxHeight: '0px'
        });
    }
});
});
```

I know it would be a lot 'easier' and 'cleaner' to change the css class/ID on click, but since what I'm working in is an already built/complicated magento theme, I figured I'd go this route at first, then focus on retooling it later down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/PnU34/1/)

Simply removed this code

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
if ( ! $(e.target).closest('#mobnav-trigger').length ) {
    $('#search_mini_form').css({
        display: 'block'
    });
    $('#mobnav').css({
    width: '48%',
    transition: 'width 0s'
    });
    $('.vertnav-top.mobile').css({
    width: '48%',
    transition: 'width 0s',
    maxHeight: '0px'
    });
    $('.vertnav-top.mobile.show').css({
    maxHeight: '0px'
    });
}
});
```

Comment: It was left over from before I added in the submenus and noticed there was an issue with them. Sorry. I've only been learning jquery since Thursday of last week. Still really new to me. Now I'm just trying to figure out how, if the menu is already open, that on second click of the #movnav-trigger, I apply a css rule. To hide the menu.